# Rewriting the Friendly urls without php extension

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I'm using Wordpress to build this website but suddenly ran across some issues with SEO.

Currently I have link like : 
`cart/?bino=cart&gid=3`

But what i want to achieve is:

`cart/service/x-service/`

I know this is possible if i would have cart.php?bino but this case is a bit different. Would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to provide more details. Otherwise there is no way we can help here. Please explain what _exact_ URL should be usable for the example you give, no just roughly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments your question is vague. I can only make some suggestion here for what apepars to me plausible given the little information you provided. You probably have to tweak things for your specific situation because of that.

I assume that the `gid` argument can only assume numerical values and that the `bino` argument can take arbitrary "words" as value. If so this probably is what you are looking for, it takes care of both sides: redirection the "old" URL scheme and internally rewriting the new scheme:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)bino=(\w+)(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)gid=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?cart.php/?$ /cart/%1/%2 [R=301,QSD]

RewriteRule ^/?cart/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /cart.php?bino=$1&gid=$2 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).